# rails factory girl comparison failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

**_spec.rb**

```
 context 'find discount coupon' do 
        it 'if coupon suitable for use' do 
          coupon = Factory(:standart_discount_coupon)
          DiscountCoupon.find_discount_coupon(coupon.coupon_no).should eql({:success => true, :error => nil, :coupon_id => coupon.id })
        end
      end
```

I have this test and when I run it,I encounter this error.

```
 1) DiscountCoupon find discount coupon if coupon suitable for use
     Failure/Error: DiscountCoupon.find_discount_coupon(coupon.coupon_no).should eql({:success => true, :error => nil, :coupon_id => coupon.id })

       expected: {:success=>true, :error=>nil, :coupon_id=>1060}
            got: {:success=>true, :error=>nil, :coupon_id=>1046}

       (compared using eql?)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
       -:coupon_id => 1060,
       +:coupon_id => 1046,
        :error => nil,
        :success => true
```

Why the copon_id's are different?

Comment: It just means you have more than one coupon with the same coupon_no in the database. You might want to try `DiscountCoupon.destroy_all` before you run that test.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the misspelling of “standard,” I guess you have nothing that stops you from having multiple coupons with the same `coupon_no` in the database. Good thing you have a test that caught that problem, even if it is only visible because your factory uses a default for the `coupon_no`.